# Webservice From SQL

Tags: sql, web-services, t-sql

Can I call a remote webservice from a Stored Procedure and use the values that areretuned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using SQL 2005/2008, you could do this from a CLR stored procedure if you have the ability to install and run these. For more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190790.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Service Broker might provide the sort of functionality you're looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

As The AntiSanta says, using a CLR stored procedure this is possible.  The real question is whether you can avoid it altogether.  It feels upside-down to call a web service from a stored procedure.  Ideally you'd have some other service/app/layer that calls both the stored procedure and a web service.  Possibly the stored proc returns parameter values for the web service, and you commit your local transaction after the WS call is complete.

This would make both debugging, deployment and support much more simple in the long run, and decouples the direct reference between the stored proc and the web service.

Comment: Do you have any other recommendations? I have a Access front end (adp writen in VBA) program with a sql backend. I woudld like to call the webservice from access but dont want to use com addin. I am calling a webserivce on remote server (headoffice) that gives the me a Purchase order number.

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server 2000 and up (if CLR is not enabled), you can use COM through stored procedures (`sp_OACreate`, `sp_OAMethod`, etc) if you have an existing COM wrapper for your web service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that works.

```
exec @hr = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT  
if @hr < 0 begin Raiserror('sp_OACreate MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp failed',16,1) 
return end  
exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @UrlString, false  
if @hr <0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Open failed' goto eh end  
exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'  
if @hr <0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Send failed' goto eh end  
exec @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'status', @status OUT  
if @hr <0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod read status failed' goto eh end  
if @status <> 200 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod http status ' +str(@status) goto eh end  
exec @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response OUT  
if @hr <0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod read response failed' goto eh end  
exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj  
select @response
```

......

eh:

```
exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj  
Raiserror(@msg, 16, 1)  
Return
```